# Chinese Remainder Theorem Consequence 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

The Chinese remainder theorem as stated in my textbook:
If $a,b \in \Bbb Z $ such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ then for arbitrary $c,d \in \Bbb Z$ there exists an $x \in \Bbb Z $ with
$x \equiv c\bmod a$  and $x \equiv d \bmod  b$. It then gives a proof (which I understand) showing that by taking $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ such that $pa + qb = 1$ that $x \equiv pad + qbc \bmod  ab$. What I do not understand is the $\bmod  ab $ part of this equation? Can anyone shed some light on where this came from?

Comment: Well, there is a unique solution modulo $ab$, so if $y$ is any other, then $x=y$ modulo $ab$.

Comment: @RickSanchez I understand this part now. But where I don't follow is where mod(ab) even came from at all.

Comment: I guess a deeper reason would come from CRT in ring theory. Have you studied this? The relatively prime $a,b$ correspond to comaximal ideals

Comment: I just started rings a week or two ago so nope. Oh well I suppose I will just take it for granted for now and figure it out later.

Comment: Easier to use an example.  Suppose $x\equiv 2(\mod 8)$ and $x\equiv 3(\mod 9)$... since $8*8-7*9 = 1, x\equiv (64*3-63*2) (\mod 72)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no need for introducing $\operatorname{mod}ab$ in the proof for the original statement (namely, there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}$). Once we have $pa+qb = 1$, it easily follows that

$x = pad + qbc$ does the job, since

$x \equiv qbc \equiv c \operatorname{mod} a$ where the last congruence follows because

$pa+qb = 1 \implies qb \equiv 1 \operatorname{mod} a$. Similarly

$x \equiv d \operatorname{mod} c$.

However, it is easy to check that any $y\equiv x \operatorname{mod} ab$ also does the job, which is what the statement $x \equiv pad + qbc \operatorname{mod} ab$ means.

Note that with a little more work, it can also be shown that such an $x$ is unique $\operatorname{mod} ab$.

Comment: Can you show/clarify why $x \equiv pad + qbc $ mod $(ab)$ "does the job" as you put it?

Comment: $x \equiv pad + qbc \operatorname{mod} ab$ means $x = kab + pad + qbc$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, $x \equiv qbc \equiv c  \operatorname{mod} a$. Similarly for $b$.

Comment: $x = kab + pad + qbc$. Since $kab + pad$ is divisible by $a$, $kab + pad \equiv 0 \operatorname{mod} a$. So $x \equiv 0 + qbc \operatorname{mod} a$.

Comment: Thank you!! Have a nice day.